# Using array notation instead of NSM on functions deeper then js.context.X

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

Can all objects after `js.context` be accessed with array notation from Dart? For example, I'd like to convert the following to use array notation:

```dart
var request = js.context.gapi.client.request(js.map(requestData));
```

Will the following array notation work?

```dart
var request = js.context['gapi']['client']['request'](js.map(requestData));
```

Also, should the following be done if trying to access JavaScript builtin methods?

```dart
js.context['JSON']['stringify'](jsonResp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** : Starting from [r24278](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=24278) use array notation for properties and `noSuchMethod` for methods.

---

Using `js.context['gapi']['client']` gives the same result as `js.context.gapi.client`. The main advantage of Array notation is that it avoids `noSuchMethod`. Until recently it was the only way to work around an [issue in dart2js where minified does not work with noSuchMethod](http://dartbug.com/9283). This issue is fixed, and minification should work with Dart-JS interop.

I did a little benchmark some times ago :

- For attribute access : array notation is around 10% faster than `noSuchMethod`. ( `js.context.x`  vs.  `js.context['x']` )
- For method access : array notation is around 50% slower than `noSuchMethod`. ( `js.context.f()`  vs.  `js.context['f']()` )

This last result is explained by 2 communications between *JS* and *Dart* for `js.context['f']()`. One to retrieve the function reference ( `js.context['f']` ) and an other to call this function.

Last concern, using `noSuchMethod` can increase your dart2js result size (but not so much where I had tested it).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```dart
  var hug = new js.Proxy(context['Hug']);

  var hugDatabase = new js.Proxy(context['HugDatabase']);

  hugDatabase['addHug'](hug);

  print(hugDatabase['hugs']['length']);
```

Which interacts with this JavaScript:

```js
function Hug(strength) {
  this.strength = strength;
}

Hug.prototype.embrace = function(length) {
  return 'Thanks, that was a good hug for ' + length + ' minutes!';
}

Hug.prototype.patBack = function(onDone) {
  onDone('All done.');
}

function HugDatabase() {
  this.hugs = [];
}

HugDatabase.prototype.addHug = function(hug) {
  this.hugs.push(hug);
}
```

The full example is here: https://github.com/sethladd/dart-example-js-interop/blob/master/web/dart_js_interop_example.dart